# JS: How to WAIT for an element to appear, and then do something IN a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, asynchronous, synchronous

This isn't the first time I've run into this issue, and after searching thoroughly, I've seen a lot of people with the same problem, but no solutions. I'm hoping for a magical API I've never heard of before, or maybe for someone to tell me I'm just plain-old doing it wrong. :-P

I have a script that simulates a click on an element as the first action in a loop block.

This causes a custom modal dialog to appear.

Then I need to do some stuff to this dialog, followed by simulating a click on a button.

```
for (day in daysOfWeek) {
        if (daysOfWeek.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
            daysOfWeek[day].click();
            fillOutTime(dailyTimes);
        }
    }
```

Here, I'll simplify the code in fillOutTime and include it in the loop so you can sort of see what I'm doing:

```
var day, submitButton;
for (day in daysOfWeek) {
    if (daysOfWeek.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
        daysOfWeek[day].click(); //opens dialog
        //fill out some stuff
        submitButton = document.getElementById('time_entry_submit'); //get submit button
        submitButton.click(); //click the submit button
    }
}
```

However, after the first click, there is apparently a delay where the dialog loads asynchronously.

What I would like to be able to do, is to wait until this dialog appears, and THEN execute the rest of the code in the loop.

---

Okay, here's what I've already tried:

1. setTimeout() and setInterval() - These didn't work of course, because they're asynchronous, so the loop just carries on at hyper-speed queueing up these asynch events.
2. A custom sleep function (see below). This just locks up the browser so the dialog doesn't start loading until it's done. I end up with the same problem, which is that the rest of the code still runs before it's loaded.

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Any suggestions would be monumentally appreciated!

Comment: I'm not completely sure of understanding your problem because if you're using animations, you can catch the "animationend" event, but if you're just applying a "display: block" or a "visibility: visible", then you can directly call your function after the line that changes the property. Another simple answer would be to use a callback, in your "event" variable send when raising "click" event, you can add a personalized property. something like:

e.personalCallback = function () { .... };
element.click(e);

and you can use the "personalCallback" in your listener

Comment: I don't get why it didn't worked with `setTimeout()`. Modals usually open in milliseconds, 400ms is default, 200ms on "fast" and 600ms on "slow". I think you have a scope issue on variables. But you did not provide enough code to be sure. I think no one can answer you correctly and I voted your question for a close as *unclear*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite following, but if the DOM container element is there and it loads it's content asynchronously then you can add an event listener that listens for the load, then click it:

```
var day, submitButton;
for (day in daysOfWeek) {
    if (daysOfWeek.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
      daysOfWeek[day].addEventListener('load', function(){
              submitButton = document.getElementById('time_entry_submit');
              submitButton.click(); //click the submit button
              });
       daysOfWeek[day].click(); //opens dialog

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this answer got downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I use the following backward compatible code:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, Fulfill, old = onload; // for use on other page loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Fulfill = function(fulfillDenyFunc){
  var t = this, df = [];
  this.fulfilled = false;
  fulfillDenyFunc(function(){
    for(var i=0,l=df.length; i<l; i++){
      df[i]();
    }
    t.fulfilled = true;
  }, function(){
    t.fulfilled = false;
  });
  this.then = function(doFunc){
    if(this.fulfilled){
      doFunc();
    }
    else{
      df.push(doFunc);;
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var out = I('out'), loop = I('loop'), r = '', im = M('img');
im.width = 510; im.height = 340; im.alt = im.title = 'lonely boat';
var yup = new Fulfill(function(resolve, reject){
  im.onload = function(){
    out.appendChild(this); resolve();
  }
  im.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/19/12/04/boot-1992136__340.jpg';
  im.onerror = function(){
    reject();
  }
}); // now use yup anywhere below the var
yup.then(function(){
  for(i=0,l=50; i<l; i++){
    r += i+'<br />';
  }
  loop.innerHTML = r;
});
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='out'></div>
    <div id='loop'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to process each element, click, wait for the dialog, then continue processing the next element. Hence, the use of for-loop will not be helpful.

A solution is to use a recursive function that will keep calling for the next item in the queue until reaching the last element.
The decision of how much time to wait is up to your context. I only assumed one second waiting time.

I was not able to test the function below.
Another way is to use Promise.

```js
var submitButton, index = 0, days = Object.keys(daysOfWeek);

function process(day) {
  if (!day) {
    return;
  }

  if (daysOfWeek.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
    daysOfWeek[day].click(); //opens dialog
    //fill out some stuff
    submitButton = document.getElementById('time_entry_submit');
    submitButton.click(); //click the submit button
    setTimeout(function() {
      process(days[index++]);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    process(days[index++]);
  }
};

process(days[index++]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the problem but I think I understand the question and an answer could be to observe DOM mutations on the host/parent element.

For example:

```
    observer = new MutationObserver(waitForMarker);
    observer.observe(mapDiv, {
                    childList     : true,
                    subtree       : true ,
                    attributes    : true ,
                    characterData : false
                    })

function waitForMarker(mutations, myInstance) {
    outer:
    for (var i=0; i<mutations.length; i++){
        if (mutations[i].type           == "attributes" && 
            mutations[i].target.tagName == "IMG"        &&
            mutations[i].target.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
            console.log("result")
            myInstance.disconnect();
            setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
            break outer;
        }
        if (mutations[i].type != "childList" ||
            mutations[i].addedNodes.length   == 0) 
            continue;
        for (var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j++) {
            var node = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
            if (node.tagName == "DIV" && node.firstChild && node.firstChild.tagName == "IMG" &&
                node.firstChild.src.toLowerCase().indexOf(MARKER_SRC) != -1){
                console.log(node.firstChild.src);
                myInstance.disconnect();
                setTimeout(plotTrip,0)
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```